# can not deal with sails.js session

Tags: firebase, session, sails.js

I have a `sails.js` project using `firebase` and have a problem with login function, after login i can not save `user` data in `session` i've tried many time but not worked.

thid is my `action fn`:

```
fn: async function (inputs) {

    var _res = this.res;
    var _req = this.req;
    var _session = this.req.session;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(inputs.emailAddress, inputs.password)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.user.uid);
        _session.userId = data.user.uid;
        return _res.json(data.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error => ', error);
        // return _res.redirect('back');
      });
}
```

it gives me this error when using `return _res.json()`

```
Error =>  Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
```

so all i want is to save user data in session after login.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are not using `await` for the `signinwithemailandpassword`. Furthermore, why are you doing this on the backend? It's designed for frontend use.

Comment: i'm using `then` for promise

Comment: @Dev.SheNNawY ah sorry, didn't see. Don't do this server side, do it client side

Comment: if i wanna do it server side, what is the best way ?!!